# Building int[] from values in another int[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an `int[] building;` that I want to instantiate dynamically based on another array `int[] info;`

The `info` will hold `int` ranging from 0-48

To build the `building` array.. If there is a non-zero value in the `info` array at index `ind` I want to add that index to the `building` array.

So if `info` looks like this `{0, 12, 24, 48}` I'd like building to show `{1, 2, 3}` another example `{12, 0, 0, 48}` -> `{0, 3}`

Is there a neat one liner to accomplish this?

How I have been doing it

```
int[] info = new int[]{12, 0, 0, 48};
List<int> indxs = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
    if (info [i] > 0)
        indxs.Add(i);
int[] building = indxs.ToArray();
```

Comment: The language you're using is not C++, but the question is tagged C++. Please fix this **inconsistency**. Adjust either the tag or the example.

Comment: You might write a helper, say `IndexesWhere`, similar to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want it to be a one liner? You can create a method in a utility library, or better yet an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). You should always value readability over length.

Comment: @mason Not specifically, when performance isn't too much of an issue I  like to make my code look nice. // I like the idea of extension methods. I can just push all the "mess" to one class and make the rest of my code look nice.

Comment: One liners do not necessarily make code look nice. Sure, in some cases you can do some very readable one liners with Linq or lambdas. But trying to make it a one liner for the sake of saving space is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var building = info.Select((i, idx) => i == 0 ? -1 : idx)
                   .Where(i => i != -1)
                   .ToArray();
```

This will get you the same array as you're getting now.

Here is the entire console application I used to prove it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] info = new int[] { 12, 0, 0, 48 };
        List<int> indxs = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
            if (info[i] > 0)
                indxs.Add(i);
        int[] building = indxs.ToArray();

        var newBuilding = info.Select((i, idx) => i == 0 ? -1 : idx)
            .Where(i => i != -1)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Both `building` and `newBuilding` provide you with the same output.

Answer (score 2):

```
var filtered = info.Select((x,i) => new { Value = x, Index = i})
                   .Where(x => x.Value > 0)
                   .ToArray();
```